# Individual column titles disappear after DataTable reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

After I edit a row in my DataTable and submit it, my individual column search titles cease to appear along with column visibility titles. Bear in mind please that I'm new to jQuery. This my code. I also get an error *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined* which references the line `viewData().ajax.reload()`.
Thank you in advance for any help.

```
function  viewData(){

      $.ajax({
       
      url:'process.php?p=view',
      method: 'GET'
      
      }).done(function(data){
     $('#example-table').DataTable().destroy();
      $('tbody').html(data)
      tableData() 
      $('#example-table').DataTable({
          
            
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            select: true,
            buttons: [

                'colvis',
                
                
                {
                    extend: 'collection',
                    text: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-export"></span> Export',
                    buttons: [
                       
                        {
                    extend: 'excelHtml5',
                    text: '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> Excel',
                    exportOptions: {
                          columns: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15 ]
                        
                    }
                },
                {
                    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                    text:'<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> PDF',
                     orientation: 'landscape',
                    pageSize: 'LEGAL',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15 ]
                    }
                },
                 {extend:'csv',
                text:'<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Csv'
                
                },
                {extend:'print',
                text:'<i class="fa fa-print" aria-hidden="true"></i> Print'
                }   
                    ]
                }
            ]
     
        });


      var datatableInstance = $('#example-table').DataTable()
     $('#example-table thead th').each(function () {
     var title =  $('#example-table thead th').eq($(this).index()).text();
       $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="' + title + '" />');
     });
     
     datatableInstance.columns().every(function () {
        var dataTableColumn = this;
        var searchTextBoxes = $(this.header()).find('input');

        searchTextBoxes.on('keyup change', function () {
            dataTableColumn.search(this.value).draw();
        });
        
        
     searchTextBoxes.on('click', function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
      });
     
     
     
      })
      
    }
    function tableData(){
          

    $('#example-table').Tabledit({
        url: 'process.php',
        eventType: 'dblclick',
          editButton: true,
          deleteButton: true,
          hideIdentifier: true,
          scrollY:"300px",
          scrollX:true,
          scrollCollapse: true,
          method: 'POST',
          dataType: 'json',
          columns: {
          identifier: [0, 'id'],
           editable: [[8, 'division'], [9, 'qte1'],[10, 'qte2'],[11, 'qte3'],[13, 'bl']]
        },
     
        onSuccess: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      
            
        viewData().ajax.reload();
        },
        onFail: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('onFail(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)');
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        },
     
        onAjax: function(action, serialize) {

            console.log('onAjax(action, serialize)');
            console.log(action);
            console.log(serialize);
            
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `viewData` is a function, if `viewData().ajax.reload()` should work `viewData()` should return the dataTable instance.

Comment: Yes thank you. But how come when I submit my edits the DataTable headers disappear?